# Check existence of IndexedDB database

Tags: html, indexeddb

Firstly, I started with this link [Check if IndexedDB database exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468963/check-if-indexeddb-database-exists) and I ran into problems.

Scenario:

Need to check whether a indexedDB database exists - If not exit.

First problem: `indexedDB.open()` creates a new DB if not existing. I tried to abort the transaction from `onupgradeneeded`:

```
request.onupgradeneeded = function (e){
  e.target.transaction.abort();
  dbExists = false;
}
```

But then I get the error:

> InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'abort' on 'IDBTransaction': The transaction has finished.

I also tried to delete the database using `deleteDatabase()` and it doesn't work.
Which is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if IndexedDB database exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468963/check-if-indexeddb-database-exists)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have stumbled on what I personally believe to be a bug in the IDB spec. There is no way to tell whether a database exists!

The way to achieve this in practice is merely to open the database you want to check for existance. If you get the database on success attached to `open_ctx.event.target.result`, it exists - otherwise it does not (probably, depending on your error message it could be undergoing a `versionchange` or something).

For what it's worth, Chrome developer Joshua Bell has seemingly also recognized this shortcoming. He's exposed the off-spec `webkitGetDatabaseNames()` method that returns a list of database names similar to index and store equivalents.

Comment: webkitGetDatabaseNames() is now deprecated and will be removed fairly soon. No alternative for it has been offered as far as I can tell.

Comment: See See Benny Neugebauer's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468963/check-if-indexeddb-database-exists) for the alternative to `webkitGetDatabaseNames()` : `indexedDB.databases` together with `db.name`